# Dictionary table in DB2 for statistics

Tags: statistics, db2

How to identify when a table's statistics is collected in db2?

I have collected statistics today on a particular table, but syscat.tables is showing statistics is collected a month back. So I think there should be some other dictionary table from which I can identify when statistics is collected.

Comment: The column `STATS_TIME` in `SYSCAT.TABLES` is the correct place.  How do you collect statistics (actual command)?  What output did you get from collecting statistics?

Comment: I am collecting statistics using a command like `ANALYZE TABLE <DB_Name>.<Table_Name> COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS col1,col2,col3;`

Comment: And what output do you get from that command?